# Script to write at the beginning of every line of a text file the name of the file

Tags: command-line, files, text

I would like to write a shell script that allows me to open a text file with a particular name and write the name of the file at the beginning of every line. So, if my file is called "test" and it has three lines:

```
SCORE1 567
SCORE2 434
SCORE3 789
```

the script would open it and change it to this:

```
test SCORE1 567 
test SCORE2 434
test SCORE3 789
```

Then it should save it overwriting the original file.

Ideally, the script would perform this modification to all the files in a particular folder, writing inside each one the name of that particular file in every line.

Once this process is done, I will feed these files to another script that will combine them in a single one that will be later analyzed with a spreadsheet.

Could you help me with this? I have some ideas, but I would like to read yours. I almost have not experience writing shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
awk -v var="$1" '{print var" "$0 }' "$1" > /tmp/temp.txt
mv /tmp/temp.txt "$1"
```

Give the script execution permission, as `chmod +x scriptname`

Run the script as,

```
./scriptname test
```

assuming "test" is the file that you are going to modify and you are running the script from the same folder where the file "test" is located.

Comment: It works very well! Thank you! Now I need to modify it to do the same with all the files in a certain folder :)

Comment: use a `for loop` for all file as, `for i in *; do ./scriptname "$i"; done`

Comment: Simple & elegant...  Upvoted!  ;-)